# ReactJS history.push function

Tags: reactjs

what does `history.push` do in reactjs?

I'm trying to look for a definition but I'm not sure if I'm goolging hard enough..

```
   history.push(`/group/${searchResult.id}/overview`)
```

What does that do?

Comment: I guess you are referring to [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package.

Comment: here you go https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history it pushes a new entry onto the history stack

Comment: Thanks. so what happens then when a new entry is pushed into the history stack?

Comment: The user can use it to go back and forward in browser navigation